# How to have Git Gui available from spotlight and dock on MacOS?

Tags: macos, git, git-gui

I'm a macos noob coming from windows and I'm used to have `git gui` available from start menu search.

I know I can launch by opening terminal and calling the command but that's not what I want here.

I also know I can create a shell script with .command suffix to have is available from spotlight but also not ideal.

How can I have `git gui` behave like a standalone app available from spotlight & dock permanent entry?

(Also the icon is blurry)

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps